# Loader animation in pure CSS

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I try to code loader animation inspired by this dribbble: https://dribbble.com/shots/14420202-Processing-Animation
and in comment section I found codepen with similar animation, but it is made all in JS: https://codepen.io/AbubakerSaeed/full/yLaQVdq

```
tl2
  .set(".dC-1", { rotate: 0 })
  .set(".dC-2", { rotate: 30 })
  .set(".dC-3", { rotate: 60 })
  .set(".dC-4", { rotate: 90 })
  .set(".dC-5", { rotate: 120 })
  .set(".dC-6", { rotate: 150 })
  .set(".dC-7", { rotate: 180 })
  .set(".dC-8", { rotate: 210 })
  .set(".dC-9", { rotate: 240 })
  .set(".dC-10", { rotate: 270 })
  .set(".dC-11", { rotate: 300 })
  .set(".dC-12", { rotate: 330 })
  .to(".dC-1", {
  delay: s,
  duration: s,
    rotate: 30,
})
```

I try to make pure CSS animation from it but I don't understand how to do it. Can someone explain for me how to make these two timelines in SCSS, how to translate JS code into SCSS?

Comment: have you tried putting 12 divs inside a rotating div;  you can move them around using a `transform: translate(x,y)l` css rule.

Comment: no I didn't, but I will try now. I tried only to rotate one center div while other divs rotating but it looked weird. let's try

Comment: but if I rotate whole div, smaller divs also rotate after translating them. how to do it they stay in place?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by keeping track of 2 animations:

- rotating plane with blocks that move in and out
- showing/hiding divs on a static plane.

You can sync up the animation and show/hide the blocks on the different plane when they should not be shown.

for example:
if 1 rotation would take 5 seconds,
the total animation would be 10 seconds.
where 5 seconds is spend invisible, and the other 5 seconds visible.

In the snippet bellow, i've made an example with 2 blocks.
You can expand it for as many blocks as you want.
I've made the blocks slightly visible when they should be invisible, just to show what's going on in the animation.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1f2227;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}

.spinner,
.static {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.spinner {
  animation: 5s linear infinite spin;
}

.block {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.static .b1 {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  animation: 10s ease-in-out infinite hide-1;
}

.static .b2 {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translateX(100px);
  animation: 10s ease-in-out infinite hide-2;
}

.static .b3 {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(100px);
}

.spinner .b1 {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  animation: 10s ease-in-out infinite go-in-out-1;
}

.spinner .b2 {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translateX(100px);
  animation: 10s ease-in-out infinite go-in-out-2;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes go-in-out-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  4%,
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  54% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  54.1%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes go-in-out-2 {
  4% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  8%,
  46% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes hide-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  4%,
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes hide-2 {
  4% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  8%,
  54% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  54.1%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="static">
    <div class="block b1"> </div>
    <div class="block b2"> </div>
    <div class="block b3"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="block b1"> </div>
    <div class="block b2"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I add more blocks, they are rotating too much at the start of translating back into center rotating div. I tried to add rotate(0) to translates but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much Lars. I am developing it for 12 blocks but animation goes wild. Maybe I am calculating time or percentages wrong?

Here is my code (in scss for more clarity):

```
.spinner {
  animation: 5s linear infinite spin;
}
    
$rotation: 0deg;
    
    .static {
      @for $i from 1 to 12 {
        .b#{$i} {
          transform: rotate($rotation) translateX($loader-size / 2);
          animation: 10s ease-in-out infinite hide-#{$i};
        }
    
        $rotation: $rotation + 30deg;
      }
    }
    
    $rotation: 0deg;
    
    .spinner {
      @for $i from 1 to 12 {
        .b#{$i} {
          transform: rotate($rotation) translateX($loader-size / 2);
          animation: 10s linear infinite go-in-out-#{$i};
        }
    
        $rotation: $rotation + 30deg;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    $first: 0;
    $second: 4;
    $third: 50;
    $fourth: 54;
    $fifth: 54.1;
    
    @for $i from 1 to 12 {
      @keyframes go-in-out-#{$i} {
        #{$first * 1%} {
          transform: translateX($loader-size / 2);
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        #{$second * 1%},
        #{$third * 1%} {
          transform: translateX($block-size * ($i - 1));
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        #{$fourth * 1%} {
          transform: translateX($loader-size / 2);
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        #{$fifth * 1%},
        100% {
          transform: translateX($loader-size / 2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    
      $first: $first + 4;
      $second: $second + 4;
      $third: $third - 4;
      $fourth: $fourth - 4;
      $fifth: $fifth - 4;
    }
    
    $first-2: 0;
    $second-2: 4;
    $third-2: 50;
    $fourth-2: 50.1;
    
    @for $i from 1 to 12 {
      @keyframes hide-#{$i} {
        #{$first-2 * 1%} {
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        #{$second-2 * 1%},
        #{$third-2 * 1%} {
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        #{$fourth-2 * 1%},
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    
      $first-2: $first-2 + 4;
      $second-2: $second-2 + 4;
      $third-2: $third-2 + 4;
      $fourth-2: $fourth-2 + 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from Angular Material loader using plain HTML & CSS

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:500);
* {
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.material_block {
  width: 580px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  margin: auto;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 1.35s linear infinite;
  animation: rotation 1.35s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}

.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-animation: turn 1.35s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: turn 1.35s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 45;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 45;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

svg:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: #e51c23;
}

svg:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: #e91e63;
}

svg:nth-child(3) {
  stroke: #9c27b0;
}

svg:nth-child(4) {
  stroke: #673ab7;
}

svg:nth-child(5) {
  stroke: #3f51b5;
}

svg:nth-child(6) {
  stroke: #5677fc;
}

svg:nth-child(7) {
  stroke: #03a9f4;
}

svg:nth-child(8) {
  stroke: #00bcd4;
}

svg:nth-child(9) {
  stroke: #009688;
}

svg:nth-child(10) {
  stroke: #259b24;
}

svg:nth-child(11) {
  stroke: #8bc34a;
}

svg:nth-child(12) {
  stroke: #cddc39;
}

svg:nth-child(13) {
  stroke: #ffeb3b;
}

svg:nth-child(14) {
  stroke: #ffc107;
}

svg:nth-child(15) {
  stroke: #ff9800;
}

svg:nth-child(16) {
  stroke: #ff5722;
}

svg:nth-child(17) {
  stroke: #795548;
}

svg:nth-child(18) {
  stroke: #9e9e9e;
}

svg:nth-child(19) {
  stroke: #607d8b;
}
```

```html
<div class="material_block">
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
  <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle></svg>
</div>
```